# Spring strange behaviour

Tags: java, spring

I have a class X, which has 2 constructors.

One constructor accepts single argument of type String, other constructor accepts single argument of a type Y.

Now when I try to instansiate class X from spring using constructor-args and passing it value of type java.lang.String I get Instantiation Exception.

What can be cause for this?

Comment: Could you post the Spring configuration code, as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: It's worth noting as well that if you are instantiating class X anywhere without constructor-args they will fail because you do not have a no argument constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [`java.lang.InstantiationException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html)?

If so, this is an exception thrown when something wrong (i.e. exception) happens during constructor execution. Take a look at the exact stack trace. Maybe there's some cause of the `InstantiationException` there?